# Estilizar (css) SVG sprite com com border

Tags: html, css, svg

Estou usando svg sprite e gostaria de saber como faço para estilizar esses ícones, eu consigo usar o `fill: color`, mas eu gostaria de dar um efeito hover deixando apenas a borda.

Vou colocar os códigos que tenho aqui para fazer o icone aparecer.

SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 233.1 233.1">
        <path class="st0" d="M116.5,0C52.2,0,0,52.2,0,116.5c0,64.4,52.2,116.5,116.5,116.5c64.4,0,116.5-52.2,116.5-116.5C233.1,52.2,180.9,0,116.5,0C116.5,0,116.5,0,116.5,0z M145.7,80.2h-15c-4,0-6.9,3.4-6.9,7.7v6.7h21.4l-3.5,21.7h-18v58.2h-21.9v-58.2H87.3V94.6h14.6V83.5l0,0c0.4-12.6,4.8-24.7,26.2-25.4V58h17.7L145.7,80.2L145.7,80.2z"/>
      </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.social-buttons svg use
{
  fill: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <svg class="icon-facebook">
    <use xlink:href="svg/myicons.svg#facebook"></use>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Para entender melhor, eu tenho um arquivo `myicons.svg` resumi ele a somente um dos icones, ai no html eu chamo o icone pela `class` e no css eu dou estilo a esse icone.

Gostaria de saber se consigo deixar esse icone so com borda sem preenchimento quando utilizar o :hover.

Comment: NÃO use Trecho de código (Stack Snippets) desta maneira, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento OK Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deixar o icone sem preenchimento basta adicionar `fill: transparent;` no `hover`, dessa maneira:

```
svg:hover #id { 
   fill: transparent;
}
```

A questão da borda é um pouco mais complicada pois a propriedade `border` não funciona, então minha sugestão é desenhar um `<rect>` em volta do icone com `fill:none;` e usar o traço do `<rect>` como a borda.

Comment: Sim o preenchimento blz eh tranquilo, mas o problema ta na borda. Eu li algo sobre <rect> mas eu teria que passar valores tipo x e y, e onde eu pego esses valores?

Comment: @Erick tu já tentou adicionar uma borda normalmente ali no própria tag <svg> do teu HTML? Aqui tem um exemplo bem simples de um rect em svg, p/ movimentar ele é só colocar os attr x e y. https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect

Comment: Sim ja tentei, mas se eu colocar na tag `<svg>` a borda fica em um quadrado externo a tag `<use>` que seria o certo, mas não consigo add a borda nela, pelo que vi tem que usar esse `<rect>`mesmo, minha dúvida era em relação a esses valores de `x`e `y`.  Vou dar uma olhada no link vlw

Comment: @Erick acho que agora entendi o que tu ta querendo, se o ícone não for um retângulo realmente fica um pouco mais difícil, ai tem que desenhar ponto a ponto, caso eu encontre algo te aviso.

Comment: Isso nesse caso o icone é redondo rs ... Mas vlw man vou procurar daqui tb. Obrigado.

Comment: @Erick opa, ai não é tão difícil assim, tenta desenhar um círculo então com fill:transparent; https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp

Comment: Mas o problema que é o icone do facebook então aquele F que vai dentro do circulo teria q estar com contorno tb, talvez o jeito eh criar o icone novamente em svg no illustrator so com contorno.